# incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party

Tags: c#, wcf

Https WCF service show nothing in  IE browser, but it reachable in Firefox.
by code I get **An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.**.

User name & PASSWORD Are both Correct. I check the port by telnet and All is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this error can be caused either by

- proxy Credentials
- Or Time and Date Setting of client

make sure client and server (that you have host your service on) have the same Time and Date.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are a myriad reasons that can cause this exception.  Try turning on [WCF Logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and see that helps narrow it down.